# List of lists: looping to convert strings to floats

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a data object of the type: `list[lists['string', 'string', floats]]`, but actually the floats are strings too, which I want to convert to floats. I tried the following but for some reason it still loops over the first two elements in the internal lists, but the if statement seems correct? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['bla1', 'bla2', '1.', '2.', '3.', '4.'],
    ['bla3', 'bla4', '5.', '6.', '7.', '8.']
    ]

for idx_datapoint, datapoint in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    print(f'{datapoint = }')
    for idx_feature, feature_val in enumerate(datapoint):
        if idx_feature in (0, 1):
            print(f'{idx_feature = }, {feature_val = }')
            print(f'{float(feature_val) = }')
            list_of_lists[idx_datapoint][idx_feature] = float(feature_val)
```

Thank you for your help in advance!! I think I'm overlooking something small, so sorry in advance :D

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected result is? You mention "but for some reason it still loops over the first two elements in the internal lists", but it's unclear to me what you expect out of your code.

Comment: Change `if idx_feature in (0, 1)` to `if idx_feature not in (0, 1)`.

Comment: if idx_feature in (0, 1) is causing the issue here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that some of the values of the lists have letters in them, so they cant be changed into floats. Other than that, this is how I would do it:

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['bla1', 'bla2', '1.', '2.', '3.', '4.'],
    ['bla3', 'bla4', '5.', '6.', '7.', '8.']
    ]

for i, list in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    for i2, v in enumerate(list):
        try:
            list_of_lists[i][i2] = float(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass  # change to whatever you want to do if you cant change it
```

I just tested it and it seems to work fine. Just change the 'pass' line to whatever you want to do with the values that have letters in them (like removing them or removing the letters).

Comment: Thank you!

Would you can to explain if using `list` has any advantage over / reason as opposed to using a variable name in line 6? Never seen this before and am curious! :)

Also, if I want to do nothing to the values that have letters in them, can I just leave the `pass` statement?

Thank you!!

Comment: two things. 1) because of the way the stack overflow answer textbox works, it wont show me the colours of the words I type as im typing them, only as im reading over the draft, so I automatically used the word list as a variable name which holds lists. It would make more sense if you used a variable called L or something. either way I tested it and it works. 2) yes you can just leave it as a pass statement, but keep in mind that means those 2 values will stay as strings.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

A simple try block might do the trick:

```
list1 = ['hello', '1.3', 1, 2, 3]
list2 = []
# print(list1[0].isfloat())
for i in list1:
    try:
        list2.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        list2.append(i)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 1.3, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a **not** after the if statement, because you **don't** want the first two elements from your `datapoint`.
You should do:

```py
if not idx_feature in (0, 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
"""
Checks if argument is floatable
"""
def is_float(element: any) -> bool:
    try:
        float(element)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

"""
iterates over the list of lists
"""
for lst in list_of_lists:
 list_of_lists  = [l if not is_float(l) else float(l) for l in lst]
```